# Get the intersected face of a cube

Tags: three.js

I have an application that displays a cube. When the user clicks on the cube, I must know which face was clicked.

Thank to this example, I managed to display a cube and to highlight it when the user hovers it :

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_octree_raycasting

But the only thing I know is that the user intersects the whole cube, I don't know which face.

I can solve it by creating 6 faces instead of 1 cube and check intersections on each face.

My question is : Is it possible to know which face has been clicked without creating 6 faces individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each face has a different `face.normal`, so in the demo you linked to, look at:

```
intersections[ 0 ].face.normal
```

three.js r.62